# How to find if the vector is stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, normed-spaces

Let's say I have the following equation $Ax=b$
My question is - **how can i find a vector $b$ around which the above equation is not stable?**
I have $$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0.999 \\
        1 & 1.001 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is what i have done so far. $x=A^{-1}b$ and $$A^{-1}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        500.5 & -499.5 \\
        -500 & 500 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$
So I see that the $\|A^{-1}\|=1000$ is very large. I am guessing that $\|b\|$ should be very small, but I do not know how to EXACTLY FORMALLY formulate the solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'not stable'?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I misunderstand the problem, but I think you are looking for $b$ such that a small change in $b$ causes a big change in $x$. $b=(1,1)$ is promising; the solution $x$ is very close to $(0,0)$, but if you change $b$ a little to, say, $(2,1)$, then $x$ is quite far from $(0,0)$.